# For missing data problem, show that $\frac{\frac1n{\sum_{i=1}^nD_iY_i}}{\frac1n{\sum_{i=1}^nD_i}}\overset{p}\to E(Y)$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Consider a missing data $\{(Y_i,D_i):1\le i\le n\}$. If $D_i=1$, $Y_i$ is observed; if $D_i=0$, $Y_i$ is missing. Assume that $Y\bot D$. Denot $p=E(D)$, Show that

$$\frac{{\sum_{i=1}^nD_iY_i}}{{\sum_{i=1}^nD_i}}\overset{p}\to E(Y),$$
and
$$\sqrt{n}\cdot\left(\frac{{\sum_{i=1}^nD_iY_i}}{{\sum_{i=1}^nD_i}}-E(Y)\right)\overset{d}\to N(0,\Omega),$$
where $\Omega=Var(Y)/p.$

---

The intuition for these two convergences make sense. For randomly missing problems, we can use the sum of the observed outcome($\sum_{i=1}^nD_iY_i$) divided by the number of observed outcome ($\sum_{i=1}^nD_i$) to estimate the mean of Y.

My question is that how to prove these two convergences?
For the first convergence, does the proof below make sense?
$$\frac{\frac1n{\sum_{i=1}^nD_iY_i}}{\frac1n{\sum_{i=1}^nD_i}}\overset{p}\to \frac{E(DY)}{E(D)}=\frac{E(D)\cdot E(Y)}{E(D)}=E(Y).$$

Comment: You would need the $D_i$ to be independent for this proof to work. Is that an assumption?

Comment: We assume that $D$ is independent of $Y$.

Comment: I know, but you would need $D_i$ independent from $D_j$ for $i \neq j$. It seems to me that this should be assumed for $Y$, but not necessarily for $D$ if this is supposed to model missing data.

Comment: Yes, I think $\{(Y_i,D_i):1\le i\le n\}$ is an i.i.d sample from  $(Y,D)$.

Comment: Is $E(Y) = 0$? Otherwise the statements are inconsistent.

Comment: Use CLT for second one

Comment: Fairly sure the variance of the normal distribution would just be $Var(Y$

Comment: The intuition for these two convergences make sense. For randomly missing problems, we can use the sum of the observed outcome($\sum_{i=1}^nD_iY_i$) divided by the number of observed outcome ($\sum_{i=1}^nD_i$) to estimate the mean of $Y$.

Comment: I guess you do not want the $1/n$ in the numerator in the second statement.

Comment: Yes, I update the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the $D_i$'s are independent (otherwise the desired properties would not hold true).

For the first, using the law of the large number and the independence of $D_i$ and $Y_i$
\begin{align}
\frac{{\sum_{i=1}^nD_iY_i}}{n}\overset{a.s.}\to E[D Y]=p E[Y],
\end{align}
and 
$\frac{1}{n} {\sum_{i=1}^nD_i} \overset{a.s.}\to p$,
so immediately
\begin{align}
\frac{{\sum_{i=1}^nD_iY_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^nD_i}\overset{a.s.}\to  E[Y]
\end{align}
and in particular this implies that convergence also occurs in probability.

For the second, note that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}\cdot\left(\frac{{\sum_{i=1}^nD_iY_i}}{{\sum_{i=1}^nD_i}}-E(Y)\right)
% 
= \frac{ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nD_i (Y_i -  E(Y))  }{ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nD_i } .
\end{align}
Now, we use the central limit theorem for the numerator, the law of the large number of the denominator, and the continuous mapping theorem to say that
\begin{align}
\frac{ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nD_i (Y_i -  E(Y))  }{ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nD_i } 
\overset{d}\to  \frac{Z}{p}
\end{align}
where $Z\sim N(0, \mbox{Var}(D (Y -  E(Y)) ))$.
For the variance of $Z$,
\begin{align}
\mbox{Var}(D (Y -  E(Y)) )
& = E[D^2 (Y -  E(Y))^2] - (E[(Y -  E(Y))])^2 \\
& = E[D^2 (Y -  E(Y))^2] \\
& = E[D^2] \mbox{Var}(Y)
\end{align}
Therefore it seems to me that to know the limit I guess you need more information than the one you currently have, i.e. the variance of both $Y$ and $D$.